# Calculating Rate of Change

Tags: partial-differential-equations, vectors, partial-derivative, gradient-flows

At the point $(0, 1, 2)$ in which direction does the function $f(x,y,z) =xy^2z$ increase most rapidly? What is the rate of change of $f$ in this direction? At the point $(1, 1, 0)$, what is the derivative of $f$ in the direction of the vector $2\hat i +3 \hat j+ 6 \hat k$?

I assumed that the rate of change is the same as the gradient of the function, namely $\bigtriangledown f$.
Calculating this gave me:

$\bigtriangledown f = \frac{\partial  (xy^2z)}{\partial x} \hat i + \frac{\partial (xy^2z)}{\partial y} \hat j +\frac{\partial (xy^2 z)}{\partial z} \hat k$.

$   \space\space\space\space\space\space= y^2z\space \hat i+2xz \space\hat j+ xy^2 \space\hat k $

Evaluating at point:

$\bigtriangledown f(0,1,2)= 2 \space\hat i$

Hence, the function increases most rapidly in the $x$ direction.

I am uncertain of how to approach solving the third part of the question, should I evaluate the rate of change at $(1, 1, 0)$ and then find the difference between that and the vector $2\hat i +3 \hat j+ 6 \hat k$?

Comment: Have you learned about directional derivatives?

Comment: Is it where I find the rate of change using the formula $ \frac{d f}{ds}= \bigtriangledown f  \cdot  \hat a $, where s is the distance in the given direction and $\boldsymbol{\hat a} $ is the unit vector in the direction of  $\boldsymbol a$? @Dr.MV

Comment: Yes.  That is all you need to do.  Simply take the inner product of the gradient with the prescribed unit vector.

Comment: Is this done just for the second part of the question? Or for the first and third parts as well. @Dr.MV

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** The directional derivative of $f$, in the direction of vector $\vec u$,  is just:
$$\nabla f\cdot \vec u,\quad\text{or}\quad \nabla f\cdot \frac {\vec u}{\lVert\vec u\rVert}$$
(there are different conventions, according to context).